# Как исключить работу в нескольких окнах?

Tags: php, javascript

У меня веб-приложение, в котором все добавления и изменения в БД происходят через AJAX, и, если у пользователя открыто два окна приложения и в одном из них он вносит изменения, а потом работает в другом, то возникают ошибки (например, в БД уже есть такой ID). Как можно запретить работу, если такое окно уже открыто или хотя бы как то предупредить пользователя?

Comment: Запретить невозможно. Предупредить тоже. Но возможно сделать так, что бы не было ошибок. Пример *(например в бд уде есть ай ди такой)* говорит о том, что у вас не правильный код вставки записи на сервере.

Comment: "то возникают ошибки" - веб-приложения по своей природе - многопользовательские. Где-то там, далеко, пользователями открыто множество окон, посылающих запросы Вашему коду. Считайте, что окна открыты разными пользователями и пишите код с учетом этого.

Comment: Хороше. Понял. Спасибо. Буду учитывать и писать доп проверки. Но нехотелось бы лишний раз напрягать пользователя)))

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko, Запретить невозможно. Предупредить тоже© а как же сокеты, лонг пулинг, локалсторэжд на худой конец?

Comment: @qwabra Если вы знаете, как с помощью веб-сокетов это можно запретить - пожалуйста, пишите ответ. Все вам будут благодарны!

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko, я перечислил три технологии, одна из них без связи с сервером, вас интересуют именно сокеты?

Comment: используйте https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Page_Visibility_API  - после получение фокуса на вкладке - отправляйте уточняющий запрос на сервер.

Comment: Если вас интересует как это сделать - например на каждой странице есть токен, токен уникален для страницы, и генерируется каждый раз при обновлении страницы, пишется в базу. при работе ajax и пр. все передают этот токен, и если на сервере такового нет - страница не валидна. в БД(на стороне сервера в общем) - для каждого пользователя хранится только один токен, и только из этой страници возможна работа. Но делать так не стоит, вам правильно написали в комментариях выше как именно нужно делать правильно, а этот комментарий просто для "ознакомления" об извращениях.

Comment: @qwabra Меня интересует, как с помощью сокетов\лонг пулинг (что в принципе не важно) и\или локалсторадж\куки\websql вы собираетесь решать задачу ТС.

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko речь шла не о запрещении, а видимо об одновременном обновлении страниц во всех вкладках браузера. Автора я так понимаю именно эта проблема интересует. браузерные хранилища (для предупреждений) правда сюда не подойдут, ибо можно открыть 2 страницы в двух разных браузерах.

Comment: @teran у ТС так написано *Как можно **запретить** работу, если такое окно уже открыто или хотя бы как то предупредить пользователя?*. Мне кажется, здесь сложно интерпретировать как-то по другому)

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko нет никакого смысла запрещать работу в разных окнах. единственная проблема - синхронизация контента между ними.

Comment: @teran я и не спорю с вами. Более того, согласен. Что я и выразил в первом комментарии *Запретить невозможно. Предупредить тоже...* Меня интересует, как товарищ qwabra собрался это делать.

Answer (score 0):

Нужно перед сохранением на бекенде делать валидацию и в случае ошибки уведомлять UI. На фронтенде можно запретить сохранение, только в том случае если он об этом табу знает. Ка вариант: пользователь в одном окне нажимает кнопку сохранить -> сервер сохраняет запись и оповещает об этом фронт посредствам веб-сокета -> в другом окне лисенер ловит это оповещение и налаживает запрет.

Answer (score 0):

мне удалось решить задачу с помощью функции pdo $pdo->lastInsertId();
когда в любом окне добавляю задачу в бд она получает уникальный айди и эта функция сразу возвращает последний айди , который я добавляю новой задаче на фронт энде, теперь возникает вопрос другой, можно ли установить какую то прослушку на изменение в базе данных и автоматически отобразить ту же задачу в другом окне